# Using a while loop to reject duplicate new username

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a simple new user registration function. There should be a process for assessing new usernames entered by the user which checks for duplicates in an external file and rejects them. The file `user.txt` is simply a line-by-line list of usernames and passwords separated by a comma.

Problem: the code keeps ignoring my effort to match each new user input variable `user` with the usernames stored in the text file (`line[0]`)

The contents of "user.txt" is as follows:

admin, admin
admin1, admin1
admin2, admin2
etc.

Any help appreciated thanks

```py
def reg_user():

    if username == "admin" and login == True: 
        registry = open("user.txt", "r+")

        # Requests username and prevents duplicates
        for line in registry:
            line = line.split(", ")
        while registry:
            user = input("Please enter a username to register:\n")
            if user == line[0]:
                print("Sorry, that username is taken. Try a different one.")

        password = input("Please enter a password to register:\n")
        passcheck = input("Please re-enter your password:\n")

        if password != passcheck:
            print("Your password doesn't match. Please re-enter your password.")
        else:
            print("Thanks. You're registered")
        user = registry.write("\n" + user + ", " + password)
        registry.close()
```

Comment: You seem do be doing it the wrong way round: asking for a user name for each line of your registry, instead of asking once and then going through each line of your registry to check

Comment: you should not store plain text user+password. Instead you should store salted hash with carefully pricked crypto hash functions. Do not try to implement it by your self. There is a lot of good implementations out there to use.

Comment: What does the file content look like, could you [edit] and share example ?

Comment: If each user is on a newline, and contains no comma or space then the split isn'tgoing to do anything, and `user[0]` will be `username\n`. you probably want to print `user[0]` to check and then use `strip` to remove the newline.

Comment: Consider using `csv` module. If you put all usernames into set you can easily check if user is already registered by: `if user in set_of_users ...`

Comment: Either your shown indentation is different from your actual or your for loop (i.e. `for line in registry`) will go through the entire file before you get to the while loop i.e. (`while registry`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```py
username = 'admin'
login = True

if username == "admin" and login == True:
    file = open("user.txt", "r+")
    registry = file.read().split('\n')

    # Requests username and prevents duplicates
    ok = False
    while not ok:
        user = input("Please enter a username to register:\n")
        ok = True
        for line in registry:
            if user == line.split(', ')[0]:
                print("Sorry, that username is taken. Try a different one.")
                ok = False

    password = input("Please enter a password to register:\n")
    passcheck = input("Please re-enter your password:\n")

    if password != passcheck:
        print("Your password doesn't match. Please re-enter your password.")
    else:
        print("Thanks. You're registered")
    user = file.write("\n" + user + ", " + password)
    file.close()
```

user.txt file:

```
a, foo
e, pass
```

Example interaction:

```
Please enter a username to register:
a
Sorry, that username is taken. Try a different one.
Please enter a username to register:
e
Sorry, that username is taken. Try a different one.
Please enter a username to register:
f
Please enter a password to register:
pass1
Please re-enter your password:
pass1
Thanks. You're registered
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. This is for a student assignment, so security isn't really an issue.

Comment: @pravda23 If you feel like one of the answers solves your problem, you may accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of it.